# Output printf to NSView

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, console, printf

I have a console app in C that uses printf statements to show output. Is it possible to get the printf output into an NSView, and If so, how is it done?

code:

```
printf("cpu (%.2f%%)\r",get_cpu());
```

I know in Objective-C it's possible to mix C, and C++ code, but it's outputting to the .nibs I'm not familiar with.

Comment: No, you can't "print" to a view. Set the text on a label or a text view.

Comment: So you mean something like `NSTextField *label = [label setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cpu (%.2f%%)\r",get_cpu()];`?

Comment: Add an outlet for the label in your xib so that you can access it in the code, then set the text on it.